# Ubuntu 18.04 cant load package manage ("serious problem" as implied by ubuntu itself)

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

So I´ve been using Ubuntu for a while now, trying to get used to it.
But now all of a sudden this appears

Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experiences an internal error.

and if I try to open the package as suggested by the system i get

```
Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem
Details: E:Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse), E:The list of sources could not be read like I said, not too used to Ubuntu yet. So I have no clue what to do
```

Edit:

I got told to open a file, which contains this in line 54-56

```
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
deb [arch=amd64] <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu bionic stable-17.06
# deb-src [arch=amd64] <DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu bionic stable-17.06
```

Comment: Please see my partial answer. Follow the instructions, and then report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `terminal` type this...

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`sudo -H gedit sources.list` # edit the file

Be careful not to change anything yet.

In `gedit` go to the preferences and **enable line numbers**.

Scroll down to line 55, and copy lines 54-56 to the clipboard, quit `gedit` without saving, then come back here, edit your question, and paste those lines so I can take a look for you. Then we can edit out the errors.

**Update #1:**

I've looked at lines 54-56, and there are TWO bad lines (55-56) that need to be completely removed... as the URL's are missing, and the repository doesn't exist any more anyway...

> deb [arch=amd64] < DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu bionic stable-17.06
>
> deb-src [arch=amd64] < DOCKER-EE-URL>/ubuntu bionic stable-17.06

Start the `gedit` editor as you did earlier, delete these two lines, save the file, and you're done!

Comment: Alright i got it. The 3 lines are in my original question. The page automatically changed it to links, not sure if i can change that

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the file in /etc/apt/sources.list has a broken line on that.

You can open that in whatever your preferred editor is, just make sure you are root when doing so (some gui's will do this for you)
eg in a terminal run

```
sudo gedit
```

One the file is open, go to line 55, either put a # at the beginning and save, or see if you can fix whatever is wrong with the line.

Comment: You should always use `sudo -H` when you start a graphic app from the terminal command line, or you may cause a login loop problem. Is your answer much different than mine (which is pending more info from the user)?